# some issues when i try to scale the variables

Tags: r

I have three variables named “age” “lr_scale” and “euRefVoteAfter”，the first two are numerical variables， the third one is a binary variable. And i want to use first two variables as two features to classify the third one. but i met some problems when i'm trying to scale thses two varibales. The error message says, `Error in seq.default(min(training[, 2]) - 1, max(training[, 2]) + 1, by = 0.01) :  'from' must be a finite number`  Maybe i should add some arguement when i'm doing the scaling to make the variables keep finite?
if someone can help me figure out, i'd be really appreciated!

```
library(caTools)
dplyr::select(bes,"age","lr_scale","euRefVoteAfter")
split <- sample.split(bes$euRefVoteAfter,SplitRatio = 0.75)
training <- subset(bes, split=T)
testing <- subset(bes,split=F)
training[-3] <- scale(training[-3])
testing[-3] <- scale(testing[-3])
library(class)
X1 <- seq(min(training[,1])-1,max(training[,1])+1,by=0.01)
X2 <- seq(min(training[,2])-1,max(training[,2])+1,by=0.01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some elements in the 'training' columns 1 or 2 may have missing values (`NA`) and if we don't remove them, the `min` or `max` returns `NA`.  We may need to use the `na.rm = TRUE` in `min` or `max` to remove those `NA` elements while calculating the `min` or `max`

```
X1 <- seq(min(training[,1], na.rm = TRUE)-1,max(training[,1], na.rm = TRUE)+1,by=0.01)
X2 <- seq(min(training[,2], na.rm = TRUE)-1,max(training[,2], na.rm = TRUE)+1,by=0.01)
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
> start <- c(1, 3, NA)
> end <- c(5, NA, 7)
> seq(min(start), max(end))
Error in seq.default(min(start), max(end)) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
> min(start)
[1] NA
> max(start)
[1] NA> min(start, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1
> max(end, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 7
```

If we add the `na.rm = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
> seq(min(start, na.rm = TRUE), max(end, na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Many thanks for the replying! The issue is fixed with your command!